# Removing bloat from greenplum table

Tags: greenplum

I have created some tables in Greenplum, performing insert update and delete operation. Regularly I am also performing vacuum operation. I Found bloat in it. Found solution to remove bloat https://discuss.pivotal.io/hc/en-us/articles/206578327-What-are-the-different-option-to-remove-bloat-from-a-table

However, if I truncate the table and reinsert the data, it removes bloat. Is it good practice to truncate the data from the table?

Answer (score 0):

If you are performing UPDATE and DELETE statements on a heap table (default storage) and running VACUUM regularly, you will get some bloat by design.  Heap storage, which is similar to the default PostgreSQL storage mechanism, provides read consistency using Multi-Version Concurrency Control (MVCC).

When you UPDATE or DELETE a record, the old value is still in the table and is able to be read by transactions that are still inflight and started before you issued the UPDATE or DELETE command.  This provides the read consistency to the table.

When you execute a VACUUM statement, the database will mark the stale rows as available to be overwritten.  It doesn't shrink the files.  It just marks rows so they can be overwritten.  The next time you execute an INSERT or UPDATE, the stale rows are now able to be used for the new data.

So if you UPDATE or DELETE 10% of a table between running VACUUM, you will probably have about 10% bloat.

Greenplum also has Append-Optimized (AO) storage which doesn't use MVCC and uses a visibility map instead.  The files are bit smaller too so you should get better performance.  The stale rows are hidden with the visibility map and VACUUM won't do anything until you hit the gp_appendonly_compaction_threshold percentage.  The default is 10%.  When you have 10% bloat in an AO table and execute VACUUM, the table will automatically get rebuilt for you.

Append-Optimized is called "appendonly" for backwards compatibility reasons but it does allow UPDATE and DELETE.  Here is an example of an AO table:

```
CREATE TABLE sales 
(txn_id int, qty int, date date) 
WITH (appendonly=true) 
DISTRIBUTED BY (txn_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of truncate it is better to use drop the table, create the table and then insert the data.

Comment: Why is it better?

Comment: when you do a truncate logically data will be removed but still data will be on the disk and to remove the data(dead tuples) we need to do vacuum and then load the data, this process is time taking once.  when we do we do drop which is faster operation and data is removed from the disk after drop recreate the table and insert the data. only disadvantage will be when you are having index which will become overhead.